# How to trigger reindexAllSearchableItemsWithAcknowledgementHandler and reindexSearchableItemsWithIdentifiers on CSSearchableIndexDelegate

Tags: ios, ios-extensions, corespotlight

Implementing a spotlight search plugin on iOS requires the implementation of the `CSSearchableIndexDelegate`. Is there a way to trigger `reindexAllSearchableItemsWithAcknowledgementHandler` and `reindexSearchableItemsWithIdentifiers`. I would like to be able to trigger them so I can test them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The triggers are under `Settings > Developer > CoreSpotlight Testing` on your iOS device. You may need to start Xcode and connect the device before the option becomes visible.